# How to make global helper that returns users profile name?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

How to make register helper that returns users profile name?

I want to make a global template helper that would show a users profile name in the view. So, the use case would be I have one template that list items, another for messages and another lastly displaying the item on its own page. This is what I have so far:

> client/helpers.js

```
// if we used items as a example, make its so the item template can see the specific item.
Template.items.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return Items.find();
  },
});

Template.registerHelper("usernameFromId", function (userId) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
  return user.profile.name;
});
```

> client/subscriptions.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('allUsernames');
```

> server/publications.js

```
Meteor.publish("allUsernames", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, 
    { fields: { 'profile.name': 1 }
  });
});
```

> client/templates/item.html

```
<template name="item">
 {{usernameFromId user}}
</template>
```

This does nothing, where am I in error?

> UPDATE

No changes yet, as I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Is `user` in `{{usernameFromId user}}` a user *object* or an `_id`?

Comment: @MichelFloyd An `_id` I believe as its from Meteor.users. You'll have to assume some things since I'm new to all of this.

Comment: try to put the `console.log` in the publication to debug. like @MichelFloyd mentioned, we are not so sure if it is the id or not

Comment: The rest of the code looks ok btw but it will only work if passed an `_id`.

Comment: This is the error I get in the console `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined`

Comment: do you want to have profile name of current user? if yes, try this.userId or Meteor.userId() instead of userId.

Comment: Odds are that the `user` variable you are passing to the global helper in spacebars isn't the `_id` of a user.

Comment: @Luna In this case, if a message or item belongs to a user, that users profile name appears.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Why is that? How would I find that out?

Comment: in your helper `console.log(user)` or just set a breakpoint there in inspector and look at it.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Looking in the console its still giving me the same problem

Comment: if the message has an owner/author field which contains userId, you can do var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner);

Comment: @Luna items has `userId`, could I do `Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);`?

Comment: @Luna Thanks that actually put in the right direction.

Comment: @JohnHuntington: so what is the value of `userId` in your helper? Sorry - I should have specified that rather than `user` before. Your reuse of names that mean different things makes it a bit complicated.

Comment: @MichelFloyd The value of `userId` is based on the document it belongs to. e.g. User has many items so the item belongs to a user, so it has a userId as a field.

Comment: My point is that if `Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId})` returns `undefined` then `userId` is not the `_id` of a valid user. The only other thing that might be going on is that the subscription `allUserNames` might not yet be `ready` by the time you're doing the find depending on where/how you're managing that subscription.

Comment: @JohnHuntington No problem. If it doesn't work, please edit your question with the latest code so that I can write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually correct. In order to make the global helper I had to change:

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
```

to

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
```

So the complete function is:

```
Template.registerHelper("usernameFromId", function (userId) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
  return user.profile.name;
});
```

Thanks commentators!